# Запретить нажатие на div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как при нажатии кнопки добавить `style` к `<div class="container">`?

```js
  var container = document.getElementById('mycontainer');
  function clickDiss() {
      container.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  }
```

```html
<div id="mycontainer" class="container">
<div class="box">
<div class="text">Test</div>
<button>test</button>
<input value="aaa">
<p>Там сверху должен блокировать (button и input например) после нажатия btn, а почему-то не работает(((</p>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="clickDiss();">btn</button>
```

Comment: `var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];` ?

Comment: Или `var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];` или `disabledaaa.style.pointerEvents = 'none';`

Comment: `var container = document.getElementById('mycontainer');
  function clickDiss() {
      container.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  }` <div id="mycontainer" class="container"></div> так тоже не работает

Comment: @АндрейЗахаров, так работает, вы вообще как проверяете? посмотрите инспектором после клика на контейнер.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gyujxzoc/2/ вот, посмотрите

Comment: Я так понимаю, что тебе при нажатии на батон, надо исключить возможность редактирования того что в диве?

Comment: Да, сегодня поковыряюсь в своем коде, с чем то конфликтует походу, ответ уже сам дал внизу

Answer (score 2):

Извиняюсь, тут после правки заработал, скорее у меня конфликт где то

```js
  var container = document.getElementById('mycontainer');
  function clickDiss() {
      container.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  }
```

```html
<div id="mycontainer" class="container">
<div class="box">
<div class="text">Test</div>
<button>test</button>
<input value="aaa">
<p>Там сверху должен блокировать (button и input например) после нажатия btn, а почему-то не работает(((</p>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="clickDiss();">btn</button>
```