# Запрет на нажатие DIV, после нажатия BUTTON

Tags: javascript, css, http

Повтор [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868786/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-div)

```js
  var container = document.getElementById('mycontainer');
  function clickDiss() {
      container.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  }
```

```html
<div id="mycontainer" class="container">
<div class="box">
<div class="text">Test</div>
<button>test</button>
<input value="aaa">
<p>Там сверху должен блокировать (button и input например) после нажатия btn, а почему-то не работает(((</p>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="clickDiss();">btn</button>
```

Этот вариант не подходит, как еще можно реализовать такой метод?

> Как при нажатии кнопки добавить `style` `pointer-events: none;` к
>   `<div id="mycontainer" class="container">`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#mycontainer');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

function clickDiss() {
  container.classList.add('container-pointer-events')
}
btn.addEventListener('click', clickDiss);
```

```css
.container-pointer-events {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: .5; /* для примера */
}
```

```html
<div id="mycontainer" class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="text">Test</div>
    <button>test</button>
    <input value="aaa">
    <p>Там сверху должен блокировать (button и input например) после нажатия btn, а почему-то не работает(((</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn" name="button">btn</button>
```